# iOS Swift Dequeued Reusable Cell not showing up

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I followed a tutorial earlier to get the basics of the Storyboard down and I'm using that code as a reference to write the app I'm working on. I want to test my prototype cell layout, but even though I set a value to the array at viewDidLoad it still refuses to show anything.

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    var cards = [Card]()

    @IBOutlet weak var cardsTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var detailDescriptionLabel: UILabel!


    var detailItem: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view.
            self.configureView()
        }
    }

    func configureView() {
        // Update the user interface for the detail item.
        if let detail: AnyObject = self.detailItem {
            if let label = self.detailDescriptionLabel {
                label.text = detail.description
            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:    Int) -> Int {
        return cards.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //példányosítunk egy cellát
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CardCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CardCell
        //kivesszük a sor adatait a listából
        let card : Card = self.cards[indexPath.row]

        cell.setCardNumber(card.number)
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8

        return cell
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

            self.cards = [Card(number: 123456789,type: 1)]

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.cardsTableView.reloadData()
    })
        self.configureView()
    }

}
```

I started from a Master-Detail structure and I set the class of the Detail Scene to DetailViewController and the class and identifier of the Prototype to CardCell

```
class Card{
    let number: Int
    let type: Int

    init(number: Int, type: Int){
        self.number = number
        self.type = type
    }
}


import UIKit
class CardCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var cardNumber: UILabel!

    func setCardNumber(number: Int){
        cardNumber.text = String(number)
    }
}
```

I'm sure it's something basic, but I've been messing with this for the second day now. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: When you click on the Prototype cell in the Storyboard and look in the Attributes Inspector, do you have the `CardCell` reuse identifier entered there?

Comment: Is that IBOutlet connected to the storyboard? Is the prototype cell in your storyboard actually of the class CardCell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to set the dataSource for the table view, i guess the delegate methods get never called.

Additionally add *UITableViewDataSource*, not necessary but more declarative than just the implementation

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
```

Comment: Now my class definition is `class DetailViewController: UIViewController ,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{` but still no luck.

Comment: Did you set the dataSource in the storyboard?

Comment: @LanceToth you need to CTRL-Drag from the TableView to the ViewController and click "delegate" and "datasource".

Comment: @LanceToth have you set delegate and datasource of your table view in viewDidLoad method like cardsTableView.delagate = self and cardsTableView.dataSource = self ?

Comment: Thanks guys, the CTRL-drag thing always gets me.